# Протокол подключения к Яндекс Станции

Tags: wifi, яндекс-музыка, яндекс-станция

Как работает воспроизведение на устройствах (Яндекс станциях) в одной Wi-Fi сети в Яндекс Музыке? Как происходит поиск устройств в сети? Есть ли где-то описание протокола?

Пытался разобрать приложение Яндекс Музыки, в коде что-то полезное найти не получилось

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Используется протокол MQTT.
Яндекс Станции и вообще умный дом Яндекса работают на IoT - интернете вещей. Больше информации вы можете узнать на сайте Яндекса: https://cloud.yandex.ru/services/iot-core